# MySQL - Top 10 Selling Products JOIN another table to pull Item Title

Tags: mysql

I need to join 2 tables, while only pulling the top 10 most frequent sku's from the sales.sales table.

```
Design.info table:
sku
name

sales.sales table:
basesku
```

I need to match "sku" from the design table to "basesku" from the sales table, and have the "name" column next to it.
Here's my current formula for receiving the top 10 designs from the sales.sales table:

```
SELECT basesku, count(*) FROM sales.sales GROUP BY basesku ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 10
```

A Colleague found a solution:

```
SELECT sales.sales.basesku, count(*),design.info.name 
FROM sales.sales 
INNER JOIN design.info
On sales.sales.basesku = design.info.sku
GROUP BY basesku ORDER BY count(*) DESC limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select basesku,count(*) from sales.sales sale
innner join design.info inf  on sale.basesku =inf.sku
group by sale.basesku order by count(*) desc limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SELECT statement in a WHERE clause. Something like this should work :

```
SELECT * FROM Design WHERE sku IN 
(SELECT basesku, count(*) FROM sales.sales GROUP BY basesku ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience is more SQL Server, but this might work for MySQL with what you want to achieve:

```
SELECT DI.sku, DI.name FROM
Design.info DI
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT basesku, count(*) FROM sales.sales GROUP BY basesku ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 10
) F ON DI.sku = F.basesku
```

Comment: This did match the sku to a name, but didn't give me the top 10 most frequent :/

Comment: that may be because I forgot the ORDER BY... I'll edit! Apologies

Comment: Unfortunately still only displays Sku and Name: http://puu.sh/n1u6t/6b5c8ef14e.png

Comment: Is it not limited to 10 results, or were you looking for more information with the sku and name? I think I'm mis-understanding what you are wanting to get. If you want to know the number of sales for the sku you can name the count(*) by amending the nested F: `SELECT basesku, count(*) AS sales` and making your select: `SELECT DI.sku, DI.name, F.sales`, or you can select any other information from the `Design.info` table by selecting `DI.*`